# Execute python script through Apex class

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, python

I have a custom button in Salesforce and a python script which takes the data from Accounts table, perform some logic and save it in an object 
I want to execute python script by clicking the custom button. Hence, is there any way to execute the python script through Apex class?

Answer (score 2):

You could expose your Python code as a web service in Heroku (or GCP, AWS or any other platform of your choice). Upon uploading the File you could send it to your web service which in turn will reply back to Salesforce.

Comment: can you please explain it more !

Comment: @Oumaima can you provide more details on what exactly you need to achieve? Is not clear where the file has to be stored, how it will be used, etc.

Comment: Okay I will have resumes stored locally in my pc how will i be able to run a python script( which will give a text output with resume details ) these details will be sent to a field in an object in salesforce. Im wondeing how to do it ! click a button in salesforce , a script with be executed and its result will be saved in a field in salesforce ! the script is in my pc and used anaconda

Comment: The solution in the way you are thinking it it would only work for you (the person with the script). Shouldn't other users be able to do this? Is this something you need to make available for other people as a service in the application or something for one-time activity performed only by you?

Comment: it have to be available for other people as a service in the application